# What typeface is used for this Wiezien Opini logo?

Tags: font-identification

[image]
I am wondering about name of this typeface

Answer (score 4):

It looks like [Chinese Rocks](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/typodermic/chinese-rocks/) font

[image]